# python equivalent of MATLAB statement A(B==1)= C

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

I have three numpy arrays as follows:

```
A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
B = [0, 1, 0, 0, 1]
C = [30, 40]
```

I would like to replace the elements of A which their equivalent in B is equal to 1. For the above example I would like to get this:

```
A = [1, 30, 3, 4, 40]
```

In MATLAB, I can do this:

```
A(B==1) = C'
```

Do you know an equivalent code in Python (preferably something that works when A and B are multidimensional too)? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is pretty similar:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> A = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
>>> B = np.array([0, 1, 0, 0, 1])
>>> C = np.array([30, 40])
>>> A[B==1] = C
>>> A
array([ 1, 30,  3,  4, 40])
```